# Почему segfault?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

Я новичок в C++, не могу понять, почему возникает указанная ошибка в этом небольшом коде. Строчку, в которой она возникает, я отметил.

```
template <typename T>
class A{
    public:
    int _data;
    T _obj;
    A(int data):_data(data){}
};

template <typename T>
class B{
    public:
    const static B<T> nullObj;
    B(int data):_a(new A<T>(data)){}
    A<T> *_a;
};

template <typename T>
const B<T> B<T>::nullObj(0);

template <typename T>
class C{
    public:
    const static C<T> nullObj;
    C():_a(nullObj._a){}
    C(bool t):_a(B<T>::nullObj._a){
        _a->_data++; //здесь
    }
    A<T> *_a;
};

template <typename T>
const C<T> C<T>::nullObj(false);

class _B{};
class  _A{public: _A(){}; C<_B> g;};

int main(){ 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А в чем то проблема? `_a` равно NULL, вот и падает.

Я так понимаю, это тестовое задание? Тогда бегите с этой компании. Если это продакшн код (мало вероятно, но все же) - перепишите. Не разрешают - бегите.

Есть такая болезнь у программистов "темплейт головного мозга с осложнениями в виде незнания порядка инициализации статических переменных".

Comment: @KoVadim, Вот с порядком инициализации мне и непонятно: по идее же nullObj в классе B инициализируется раньше (выше по коду).

Comment: Вы так и не ответили на вопрос - откуда этот код. Это бы немного подсказало, куда копать, кого бить.

Для понимания того, что сделал компилятор, я пользуюсь http://gcc.godbolt.org/ - в ассемблерном листинге все прозрачно.


Правило простое - статические переменные не всегда инициализируются в том порядке, в котором Вы "ожидаете".

Интересное на эту тему можно почитать на [rsdn](http://rsdn.ru/forum/cpp/335445.all). Если я правильно понял, то вначале выполняется статическая инициализация нулями, а потом уже по очереди конструкторами.

Comment: @Im ieee: Это даже в FAQ занесли: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html.

`B::nullObj` не обязательно инициализируется перед `C::nullObj`.

Comment: @VladD, я это читал, там написано «two static objects x and y which exist in separate source files», а у меня в одном всё. Вот здесь  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421671/when-are-static-c-class-members-initialized в ответе написано: «objects defined in the same translation unit ... are initialized in order of their definitions»

Comment: @KoVadim, это минимальный рабочий пример моего учебного кода, бить никого не нужно. На RSDN вроде как тоже говорится про объекты в разных файлах.

Comment: @Im ieee: По стандарту, порядок не определён. Не надейтесь на порядок инициализации, который генерирует компилятор, если только этот порядок не **гарантирован** документацией.

Comment: Уж сильно странный код для своего учебного примера.

На рсдн написано, что статические объекты инициализируются вначале нулями, а потом по очереди уже конструктором.

Если добавить немного отладочного вывода, то можно понять, что на момент вызова падающего кода, конструкторы двух других темплейтных классов не вызывались.

Comment: @VladD, по ссылке на SO цитируется стандарт, в котором, как я понял, утверждается обратное: «Objects with static storage duration defined in namespace scope in the same translation unit and dynamically initialized shall be initialized in the order in which their definition appears in the translation unit»

Comment: @Im ieee: Неприменимо. У вас не объекты, а шаблоны. Смотрите ответ ниже.

Comment: Кроме этого [C++ is a horrible language ~ Linus Torvalds](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/57918)

тут нечего добавить.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Стандарт не определяет порядок инициализации глобальных переменных, размещенных в разных единицах компиляции. 
Однако в случае, если глобальные переменные находятся в одной единице компиляции, стандарт гарантирует, что они будут проинициализированы в порядке их появления.

Другое дело, что в этом примере `template <typename T> const C<T> C<T>::nullObj(false);` не является инициализацией глобальной/ых переменных, потому что описаны шаблоны, а не переменные.

Инициализация же переменных из шаблонов происходит в момент их упоминания в коде. Посмотрите на объявление класса _A:

```
class  _A{public: _A(){}; C<_B> g;};
```

Тут впервые появляется использование шаблона `C<T>`, а именно тип `C<_B>`, и вот как только он появился, все типы с ним связанные начинают инициализироваться. Соответственно, начинает инициализироваться и глобальная переменная появившегося типа. При этом инициализации B<_B> еще нет.

Отсюда и segmentation fault.

Т.е. проблема *не в том, что порядок инициализации не гарантирован*, **порядок инициализации вполне корректно гарантирован и его по коду можно строго определить**. Он лишь не тот, который ожидается программистом.

Для исправления проблемы можно после объявления _B и перед _A добавить template class B<_B>;, что инициализирует B<_B> до C<_B> (а значит и их статические переменные).

Comment: @smallFish: По стандарту, порядок инициализации статических полей шаблона **не** гарантирован. То, что конкретный компилятор с конкретными настройками инициализирует их в том порядке, который встречается в исходном тексте — случайность, на неё нельзя полагаться.

Comment: Не совсем. 
C++ Standard, section 14.7.1 [temp.inst]:
Unless a member of a class template or a member template has been explicitly instantiated or explicitly specialized, the specialization of the member is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires the member definition to exist; in particular, the initialization (and any associated side-effects) of a static data member does not occur unless the static data member is itself used in a way that requires the definition of the static data member to exist

Comment: Иными словами, стандарт гарантирует, что во время инициализации статическая переменная не появится до того момента, пока the static data member is itself used in a way that requires the definition of the static data member to exist.

В данном случае, как бы мы ни хотели, но B<_B> не может появиться раньше, чем C<_B> из-за этого правила стандарта.

Comment: К слову, я сам был очень удивлен такой сложности этой проблемы, и, когда решения еще не было, а комментарии мне казались неясными, продублировал этот вопрос на другом форуме (с которого, опять же к слову, этот форум слизан). И там была большая дискуссия: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25525688/static-initialization-in-one-compilation-unit с решением, которое, имхо, шире, чем Ваше.

Comment: @smallFish, спасибо за ответ, в принципе неплохое решение, только в общем случае нужно знать аргументы шаблона заранее. Мне в голову пришел другой вариант, похожий на первый ответ на SO: написать в конструкторе C : `B<T>::nullObj; _a=nullObj._a;`, ну и какие-нибудь прагмы, чтобы компилятор не ругался, тогда ошибок нет. С другой стороны, обратиться к C<T>::nullObj без обращения к B<T>::nullObj все равно не получится, поэтому окончательное решение для рабочего кода, как это часто бывает в таких случаях, совсем другое.

Comment: @Im ieee, так это все же не головоломка (для любителей сборки кубика Рубика), а модель рабочего кода?

Интересно, сколько ошибок будет в него вноситься в процессе эксплуатации при каждой модификации исходного ТЗ?

Comment: @avp, это код учебной программы, поэтому никаких ТЗ не будет. Правда, непредвиденных ошибок действительно много.

Comment: И в какой фирме (если не секрет, конечно) такому учат?

Comment: @smallFish: Ваша цитата не гарантирует порядок. Там сказано «does not occur unless», но не «occurs when». Кроме того, отсутствие гарантии порядка явно подтверждено цитатой в моём ответе.

Comment: @VladD, насколько я понимаю, "does not occur unless" означает, что пока нет типа B<_B>, объявления статической переменной B<_B> точно не появится. При этом " the specialization of the member is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires the member definition to exist" гарантирует, что объявление статической переменной C<_B> будет после объявления типа с конструктором по умолчанию, который как раз "requires the member definition to exist".

Answer (score 2):

По стандарту ([N3797](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf), §3.6.2/2)

> Definitions of explicitly specialized class template static data members have ordered initialization. Other class template static data members (i.e., implicitly or explicitly instantiated specializations) have unordered initialization.

В вашем случае шаблон не является специализированным, то есть первое процитированное предложение неприменимо. Согласно второму предложению, порядок инициализации **не специфицирован никак**.

То есть относительный порядок инициализации не гарантирован, даже если инициализация находится в одном и том же файле.